# Adaptive card are not showing in webchat where as showing in MS Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, web-chat

We are using the below code to display the adaptive card in Webchat and Teams.
Its working correctly in Teams and in Webchat its displaying as a line.

[image]

[image]

Adaptive card is showing up in MS teams

[image]

Adaptive card is showing up in Webchat

[image]

Comment: Never post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

Webchat and msteam are different channels so it's required additional properties for rendering actions in the bot framework.

The MS Teams Adaptive card required special property with the name msteams to the object in an object submit action’s data property in order to access this functionality.

```
{
"type": "Action.Submit",
"title": "Click me for messageBack",
"data": {
"msteams": {
"type": "messageBack",
"displayText": "I clicked this button",
"text": "text to bots",
"value": "{\"bfKey\": \"bfVal\", \"conflictKey\": \"from value\"}"
},
"extraData": {}
}
}
```

As per your card "id" property is missing in the **"AdaptiveSubmitAction"** and need to differentiate both channel property Data values in the implementation.

Replace the **"AdaptiveActionSet"** code with the below one.

```
new AdaptiveActionSet() {
Actions = new List < AdaptiveAction > () {
    new AdaptiveSubmitAction() {
        Title = ResourceString.SubmitText,
            Id = ResourceString.SubmitText,
            if (turnContext != null && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channels.Msteams) {
                Data = new Jobject {
                    {
                        "msteams",
                        new JObject {
                            {
                                "type",
                                "messageBack"
                            }, {
                                "displayText",
                                "Hello"
                            }, {
                                "text",
                                "Hello"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        else {
            Data = new JObject {
                {
                    "type",
                    "messageBack"
                }, {
                    "displayText",
                    "Hello"
                }, {
                    "text",
                    "Hello"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Microsoft Docs : [MS Team Docs](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/)

Comment: In this card there is only ShowCard action in AdaptiveActionSet. Submit action is added in the show card action Card.

Comment: What happened when you are using the above code? Also, maintain the "id" inside "AdaptiveShowCardAction()".

Comment: @Aiswarya hopping the issue is already resolved.

Comment: Yes it worked by rendering the card properly in react js

Comment: Great!! If it is resolved then you can accept this as an answer and this will help others in future reference.